# Port Forwarding For SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos6

I have a two server in a network and one of them no have internet connection (srv2).

I want to forward 23 port on server (srv1) which have a internet connection to port 22 on no internet connection server (srv2)

my ifconfig on srv1

```
eth0      inet addr:95.x.x.x  Bcast:95.x.x.x  Mask:x.x.x.x

eth1      inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0              

lo        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

and my other server ifconfig (srv2 have no internet connection)

```
eth0      inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.0.0.3  Mask:255.255.255.252

lo        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

on srv1 cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward result 1

I can forward 3055 (srv1) port to 3050 (srv2) with this rules;

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3055 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:3050
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3050 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1
```

But i can't forwarding 23 (on srv1) to 22 (on srv2) for ssh connection.

Can you help about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall 23 port is a telnet port. You can't route a system port (all two digits ports). But you could make a routing from a port like 1234 to 22 with no problem at all.

It is based on my experience from quite long time ago.